# Create a simple loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, webdriver

How can I tell to my code to not end and start again ?
From the 1st `try:`

running = True
while running:

```
f = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
for word in f:
    if word == "\n":
        continue
    
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Newtweet_button).click()
sleep(0.5)

   
driver.find_element_by_xpath(message_paste).send_keys(word)
        
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(post_tweet_xpatch).click()
    sleep(1)

except (ElementClickInterceptedException):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(cross_button).click()

except (NoSuchElementException):
    print("tweet not send")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(cross_button).click()
    sleep(4)

else:    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(close_button2).click()  
    sleep(4)
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi fahad, It looks like you've added the code without indentation, it will be easier to answer if you add the indentation like it's shown in your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
running = True
while running:
    #your code
```

This won't stop until running is set to false: `running = false`

Or you can have a count:

```
count = 0

while count >= 3:
    #your code
    count += 1
```

*This will make the code run 3 times.*

**EDIT:** to close your file you need to not read the file variable, like this:

```
 with open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
      file = f.readlines()
      for word in file:
          if word == "\n":
             continue
```

Comment: While loop is running perfectly thank you !

Comment: But I have a problem I am not able to close my f file with `f.close()` I am getting this error `f.close()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: glad that your loop is now working, would you be able to show me your code what is preventing your file from closing? you can do this by editing your question above

Comment: you can check now

Comment: is this the reason why the code is reading only the last line of the text file, and it always send the last line as key

Comment: do you know why my code copy the last line of the file instead of the first line ?

Comment: i do not sorry.